# Binding to the keydown event with jQuery on function

Tags: jquery, keydown

```
sqHTML = "<div id=\""+sqStringTemp+"\" class=\"puzzlesquare\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"puzzlesquareinput\" maxlength=\"1\" style=\"text-transform: uppercase\"/></div>";
jQuery("#gridpuzzleouter").append(sqHTML);

jQuery(".puzzlesquareinput").on('keydown', '', function() {
    alert("keydown...");
});
```

I am not yet getting any alert out of `.puzzlesquareinput`. I am wondering how to bind to the keydown event of each `.puzzlesquareinput`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
jQuery(".puzzlesquareinput").on('keydown', function() {
   alert("keydown...");
});
```

---

your current code is working... make sure there are no javascript error... and/or wrap your code on `$(document).ready`... try checking the console...

here's a fiddle of your current code which is working http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/fcTqP/

Comment: I think you are right. There is an error coming out of the console that needs fixing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to delegate event to parent of `.puzzlesquareinput` that is `#gridpuzzleouter` in your case. Ensure you **included jquery successffully** and bind event in **document.ready**.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cWGRX/)**

Change to

```
jQuery("#gridpuzzleouter").on('keydown', '.puzzlesquareinput', function() {
         alert("keydown...");
});
```

Comment: There is no alert coming out still.

Comment: Check update answer with live demo, ensure you included jquery successffully and bind event in document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".puzzlesquareinput").on('keydown', '', function() {
                                           ^this is the selector, and you are
                                            selecting nothing
```

There is no point doing that unless you want it to apply to all `.pzzlesquareinput` you later created. Try this instead:

```
$(".puzzlesquareinput").keydown(function(){
    //...
});

<input class="puzzlesquareinput">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/2cYYB/